# Calling functions with different variable types

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-datatable

I need to call the function that will get the value of a datatable cell with the `ColIndex`, either a text (column name) or an integer (`columnindex`).

To avoid writing two functions that, I wrote this code:

```
Public Function DTableCellValue(ByRef RowData As DataRow, _
                                    ByVal ColIndex As Object, _
                                    Optional ByVal DefaultVal As String = "") As Object
        Try
            Dim ret As Object = RowData.Item(ColIndex)

            If IsDBNull(ret) Then
                Return DefaultVal
            Else
                Return ret
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        End Try
    End Function
```

Can you tell me if it uses bad coding practices or is potentially problematic?

Comment: What do you mean by "issues"? Do you mean will it run? Is it bad coding practice? Might it cause problems down the line? Try and be as specific as you can about what your question is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use this method quit often by passing an `Integer` you will get performance problems because of the boxing and unboxing of the struct.

My advice would be to write two methods one using an `Integer` and the other using a `String` as argument.

---

Based on the [naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) you should name methods by using a verb or a verb phrase. `DTableCellValue` looks by its name more as a property than a method.

Based on the same guidelines method arguments should be named using `camelCase` casing. Although VB.NET isnt case sensitive I would like to suggest to follow these guidelines.

---

The `try..catch` is in its current form senseless because if an exception is thrown you are just rethrowing it.

---

A construct like

```
If condition Then
    Return Value
Else
    Return otherValue
End If
```

can be simplified by removing the redundant `else` like so

```
If condition Then
    Return Value
End If 
Return otherValue
```

because if the condition is `true` the `else` won't be reached.

---

Implementing the mentioned points (leaving aside the method name) leads to two methods like so

```
Public Function DTableCellValue(ByRef rowData As DataRow, _
                                    ByVal colIndex As Integer, _
                                    Optional ByVal defaultVal As String = "") As Object
    Dim ret As Object = rowData.Item(colIndex)

    If IsDBNull(ret) Then
        Return defaultVal
    End If

    Return ret

End Function

Public Function DTableCellValue(ByRef rowData As DataRow, _
                                    ByVal colIndex As String, _
                                    Optional ByVal defaultVal As String = "") As Object
    Dim ret As Object = rowData.Item(colIndex)

    If IsDBNull(ret) Then
        Return defaultVal
    End If

    Return ret

End Function
```

Comment: I don't think a generic method would work since String is a noninheritable class.

Comment: Or rather, you could, but you couldn't put a proper type constraint on it.

Comment: i did, making colindex and object variable instead of a type contraint

Comment: @Heslacher what are your suggestions for names for this function

Answer (score 4):

I'm a little late to the party so I will not repeat what [@Heslacher](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/29371/heslacher) said in his/her [review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/102045/36214).

---

A method that doesn't use any members from a class instance should be static (shared). If the method reside in a module (not a class) then you're fine because the method is static (shared) by default.

Now, since it looks like you're creating an extension method, we'll put the method in a module so we can append the [Extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.extensionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute.

```
Public Module DataRowExtensions

    <Extension()>
    Public Function DTableCellValue(...) As Object
```

Microsoft provide a .net assembly named *System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll* which extend some of the classes located in the the *System.Data* namespace. One very related class is the [DataRowExtensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions(v=vs.110).aspx) class and its `*Field<T>* methods. It's almost identical to your method except the ability to provide a default value.

So I suggest we use the same name (method and parameters) and make it generic.

```
Public Function Field(Of T)(row As DataRow, columnIndex As Integer, Optional ByVal defaultValue As T = Nothing) As T
```

The *DataRow* class has a method named [IsNull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.isnull(v=vs.110).aspx) which accepts both a string (column name) and an integer (column index). Combine this with the short-circuit ternary [if operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx) and the return statement becomes an easy to read one-liner.

```
Return If(row.IsNull(columnIndex), defaultValue, row.Item(columnIndex))
```

Apply all the suggestions and the code will look like this:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module DataRowExtensions

    <Extension()>
    Public Function Field(Of T)(row As DataRow, columnIndex As Integer, Optional ByVal defaultValue As T = Nothing) As T
        Return If(row.IsNull(columnIndex), defaultValue, row.Item(columnIndex))
    End Function

    <Extension()>
    Public Function Field(Of T)(row As DataRow, columnName As String, Optional ByVal defaultValue As T = Nothing) As T
        Return If(row.IsNull(columnName), defaultValue, row.Item(columnName))
    End Function

End Module
```

---

**Usage**

```
Dim firstName As String = table.Rows(0).Field(Of String)(0, "(null)")
Dim firstName As String = table.Rows(0).Field(Of String)("firstName", "(null)")
```

Inferred by the type of the default value:

```
Dim firstName As String = table.Rows(0).Field(0, "(null)")
Dim firstName As String = table.Rows(0).Field("firstName", "(null)")
```